# IOS 5 error when attempting to set label to hidden

Tags: objective-c

I have a label that serves as a warning when certain conditions are not met.  But when I attempt to set the label to hidden with the following code:

```
infoWarning.hidden = YES;
```

for context, here is the full code:

```
if (weightC < 50 || (waistM1 < 20 && waistM2 < 20 && waistM3 < 20) || (ageC < 18 )) 
{
    infoWarning.hidden = NO;

    NSString *warning = @"";
    if(ageC < 18)
    {
        warning = @" an age over 17";
    }
    if (averageWaistM < 20) {
        if (warning != @"") {
            warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, and", warning];
        }
        warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ a waist measurement", warning];
    }
    if (weightC < 50) {
        if (warning != @"") {
            warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, and", warning];
        }

        warning = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ a weight", warning];

    }


    if (warning!=@"") {
        [infoWarning setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please add%@.", warning]] ;
    }


} else {
    if(gender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {

    }

    else if(gender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {

    }
}
```

That I thought would work, but (obviously) does not. It gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the line:

infoWarning.hidden = YES;

infoWarning does exist, is synthesized, and is connected to the UILabel in Interface Builder. Could you help me identify the problem and make it work?

This is the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@class Preferences;
@class Utilities;


@interface BodyFatCalculatorViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *age;
    IBOutlet UITextField *waist1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *waist2;
    IBOutlet UITextField *waist3;
    IBOutlet UITextField *weight;

    IBOutlet UILabel *waist;
    IBOutlet UILabel *currentWeight;

    IBOutlet UILabel *bodyFat;
    IBOutlet UILabel *averageWaist;
    IBOutlet UILabel *veryLean;
    IBOutlet UILabel *veryLeanBorder;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *veryLeanCheckmark;
    IBOutlet UILabel *fit;
    IBOutlet UILabel *fitBorder;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *fitheckmark;
    IBOutlet UILabel *average;
    IBOutlet UILabel *averageBorder;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *averageCheckmark;
    IBOutlet UILabel *atRisk;
    IBOutlet UILabel *atRiskBorder;
    IBOutlet UILabel *atModRisk;
    IBOutlet UILabel *atModRiskBorder;
    IBOutlet UILabel *atHighRisk;
    IBOutlet UILabel *atHighRiskBorder;

    IBOutlet UILabel *infoWarning;

    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *gender;

    NSMutableArray *arrayAge;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *age;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *waist1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *waist2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *waist3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *weight;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *waist;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *currentWeight;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *bodyFat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *averageWaist;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *veryLean;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *veryLeanBorder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *veryLeanCheckmark;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *fit;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *fitBorder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *fitCheckmark;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *average;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *averageBorder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *averageCheckmark;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *atRisk;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *atRiskBorder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *atModRisk;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *atModRiskBorder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *atHighRisk;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *atHighRiskBorder;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *infoWarning;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *gender;

-(IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
-(void)calculate;


@end
```

Problem has been fixed, thank you to those who responded and looked into it. The problem was actually an array with the limits that were too small (I don't know why that caused this to break, they weren't at all related...) and so I increased the limits and now the infoWarning works great.

Comment: Well, maybe you should show us the line where you set hidden to YES??

Comment: So, the code that is giving you the error is not actually the code you have put in the question? Can you show the declaration, property etc of infoWarning and also tell us in which method you are trying to hide it?

Comment: @ Hot Licks: the:   infoWarning.hidden = YES;     is the exact line it has the error on.                                                    @jrturton: I'll edit the post and add those. Sorry.

Comment: I haven't seen a revision to your post in nearly 20 minutes.  Are we to assume you've found the problem?

Comment: @Jeremy, sorry I couldn't get the edit to work. I tried then, but only just now figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete error from the console might help but given "EXC_BAD_ACCESS error" in the line

```
infoWarning.hidden = NO;
```

suggests that there is a problem with `infoWarning.hidden`, what are the `@property` and `@synthesize` statements?

To compare the contents of strings use:

```
[warning is equalToString:@""]
```

not:

```
warning != @""
```

which compares the pointers to the strings.

But in your case why not just use:

```
warning.length != 0
```

Comment: Excellent tip. I have changed that, but the problem is in how I've declared hidden it seems, and my code still does not work.

Comment: BTW, I would love to give you the log info you asked about, but I'm afraid to admit I don't know how...